# Dealing with the same setting in different config files

Tags: scala, playframework, config, playframework-2.2

I was suggested to use 2 or more config files for different modes:

```
play -Dconfig.file=/conf/dev_application.conf run
```

Well, how can I deal with some common settings that are **the same** for different modes? Copy-pasting those is not what I'd use.

I'd use one common config file if it was possible:

```
play -Dconfig.file=/conf/dev_application.conf /conf/common_application.conf run
```

As far as I'm concerned, it's not possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import settings in another configuration file via use of an `include` statement:

```
# Note that the name of the file being included must be quoted
include "common_application.conf"
```

This will import all configuration entries from your common configuration. You can then also override the values of any these common keys lower down in your mode-specific config file:

#### common_application.conf

```
foo=0
```

#### dev_application.conf

```
# Import common configuration
include "common_application.conf"

# Override common configuration
foo=1

# Dev configuration
bar=0
```

Comment: I'll have to specify the current config file always depending on the mode, can I get rid of this? I'd like the default config to be "my_dev_application.conf" for development mode, "my_prod_application.conf" for production.

Comment: Unless you fork Play and change the internals of ``COnfiguration.scala``, I think you have to specify the config file you want to use in a JVM argument. Maybe @serejja's answer is the approach to take if you don't like the idea of having to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, look what I found:

[GlobalSettings](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings) has an `onLoadConfig` method, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
  val richConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"${mode.toString.toLowerCase}_application.conf"))
  super.onLoadConfig(richConfig, path, classloader, mode)
}
```

This way you can keep your common settings in `application.conf` and environment-specific settings in `prod_application.conf` or `dev_application.conf` (but I did not recheck the values of `mode` parameter so the names may differ)

**EDIT**

Yes, I just rechecked the [Mode](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Mode%24@Mode=play.api.Mode.Value) values. Here they are:

```
val Dev: Value
val Prod: Value
val Test: Value
```

So using this approach you can name your conf files as `dev_application.conf`, `prod_application.conf` and `test_application.conf`

Comment: Thanks. 1) have you tried this? I read this might not work. 2) do you know how can I run the application in any arbitrary mode, let's say "my_super_production"?